# Can't get list of users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to show list of users in my app. I use default `Auth` system from firebase. But response always empty.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                        print(snapshot)
                    })
```

But `snapshot` is always `Snap (users) <null>`

Comment: Using Firebase Auth doesn't automatically put anything in your Firebase Database. If you aren't already, you probably want to add something to `MyDatabase/users` when a user registers.

Comment: @ConnorNeville so to add some fields or modify/delete Auth users i should create my own Users with link to Auth users?

Comment: @Arti yes. I'll post an answer outlining that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering a user with Firebase Authentication, by default, does nothing to modify your Firebase Database. Authentication and Database are two pretty much unrelated services. It's a common practice, once you register a user, to save an entry in your Database with their `uid`, so you can relate the two services:

```
let auth: FIRAuth? = FIRAuth.auth()    // The authentication object
auth?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    // If registration was successful, `user` is a FIRUser with a uid
    if let userId = user?.uid {
        let exampleDBPath = FIRDatabase.database().child("users").child(userId)
        // Write the user object, for instance a user name or other data, to this path
        exampleDBPath.setValue(someJSONAboutTheUser) { (error, result) in
            // Now you have a spot to modify your user in the database
        }
    }
}
```

This `FIRUser` created from registration is the same type of object you'll get when a user tries to sign in, so you can find the correct user in the database via the same uid.

Comment: I just wanted to delete anonymous user after user logged in. So need to leave this accounts ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, just don't store anything in the Database if the user logged in anonymously. Then, once they log in with an account, get the path of the current user by their uid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555145/remove-anonymous-user-from-auth-database    could you check my new question:)

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Authentication system does not automatically insert anything into the Firebase Database. I guess your database is empty, which is the reason for `snapshot` being `null`.

Your code looks correct, but as I said there might not be any data in your database to receive.

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve you should consider storing user meta data in you database. A good point to do so would be directly after the user creation.