# Remove anonymous user from Auth database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using **Firebase** database and little confused with next situation.

Let's imagine i have todo app. I use standard Firebase `Auth` system for sync `items` between user devices. But in other case user could work anonymously without synchronization.

**Step 1:**

User launch app first time, and in `AppDelegate` i created Anonymous user:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  if let _user = user {
    if _user.isAnonymous {
        print("User logged in as anonymous. Saving uid to user defaults storage.")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(_user.uid, forKey: "uid")
    } else {
         print("User logged in with email: \(_user.email)")
    }
  } else {
     FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
        if let _error = error {
           print("Anonymous signIn error: \(_error)")
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:**

This anonymous user created few todo items and decided  signUp:

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!)
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { user, error in
    if error == nil {
        FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!,
                                       password: passwordField.text!)
     }
 })
```

So i have modified previous code and change owner of created todo items:

```
if let prevUserUID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid"), prevUserUID != _user.uid {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("todo-items").queryOrdered(byChild: "user").queryEqual(toValue: prevUserUID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for item in snapshot.children {
        var todoItem = TodoItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        todoItem.user = _user.uid
        todoItem.ref?.setValue(todoItem.toAnyObject())
    }
  })
  print("Data migrated.")
}
```

Ok everything works. But, now user logged out. An i created new anonymous user. Then he login again and i merge data. But i can't link account, because i already did it before. And i can't delete anonymous user from `Auth` database([my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549434/cant-get-list-of-users/41550957?noredirect=1#comment70314862_41550957)). And we get **zombie**! unused anonymous account. And if user will log in/log out 1000 times we get 1000 anonymous accounts.

Comment: What is the end goal? The subject says remove auth user from database (a contradiction). Why are multiple anon accounts being created? How do you know they belong to the same user, and why do we care if they stick around? Either it's okay to have anon users creating stale data or you shouldn't be allowing anonymous writes? Should the data expire after some period of time? Be deleted as soon as the anonymous user leaves? What is the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is how to delete anonymous accounts from Auth database. When user login from anonymous account i move all data that belongs to anonymous into user account. And then i don't need this anonymous because if user log out, he never enter into it again `signInAnonymously()` will create new instance.

Comment: @Kato so now i have only one device, and create one account. But i logged in/ logged out - 20 times and have 20 unused anonymous accounts.

Comment: @Arti. - Having the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you link the credential with the currentUser you are logged already, don't need for:

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn
```

You keep the UID of the anonymous user.

If user already have an account, in this case you need to:

```
currentUser.delete()
```

And then logIn with the credentials provided