# Firebase real-time database (Get other user info based on UID) with REST

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app created with Firebase real-time database and I've created a few users, all with REST methods found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

I can get the user info for the current user, but I would like to have a REST endpoint to fetch all the users (UID, email, displayPhoto, name, etc) or at least a user by UID. I haven't found this method in the link above.

I know that there is an SDK to do that (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), but I would like to do this with REST since the full app is using REST.

Does anybody know if this is possible and has the rest endpoint?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public REST API to get a list of all users. The reason for this is that getting a list of users is considered a sensitive operation, and allowing that from client-side code would be risky.

The common way to implement your use-case is to build your own endpoint, either on a server you already control, or with Cloud Functions. There you can use the Admin SDK to get the list of users, and then return that to your caller. Make sure to limit what data you return and to properly secure that endpoint though, as otherwise you'll be putting your user's information at risk.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! Will try with Cloud functions. Thanks for the security information, will keep that in mind. Also, this is just a POC app.

Comment: I actually just noticed that you mentioned the Firebase Realtime Database too. That's another alternative that lots of developer use: have each user write their pertinent profile information fo the database (either Realtime Database or Firestore) and read it from there. For more on that approach see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676121, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550957,